# Force Sharepoint to classic view

Tags: sharepoint

Where can I force SharePoint 2013 online to always use classic view for every user?

I'm unable to find a setting that will only display the SharePoint 2013 online pages in classic view.

Comment: When you load SP2013 online in classic view, setting is stored in cookie. If you clear the cookie after you close the browser then next time it will again load in new online view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to Microsoft's documentation **[here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-the-default-experience-for-lists-or-document-libraries-from-new-or-classic-66dac24b-4177-4775-bf50-3d267318caa9)**:

> #### Change the default experience for all lists and document libraries (for administrators)
>
> 1. Choose **Admin centers** and then **SharePoint**
>    [image]
> 2. Choose **Settings**
> 3. Next to **SharePoint Lists and Libraries experience**, select either **Classic experience** or **New experience (auto-detect)**.
>    [image]

Comment: That's for lists and libraries. And there's an Advanced section on each List Settings/Library Settings page. But what about pages in the SitePages folder?

Comment: @vapcguy I'm not 100% certain, but I believe if you want "classic" pages, your best bet is to create publishing pages (in the Pages library that you get upon activating the [Publishing infrastructure feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/features-enabled-in-a-sharepoint-publishing-site-3ab3810c-3c2c-4361-9d0e-0cbe666ea0b0#:~:text=Publishing%20features%201%20Navigation%20and%20ribbon.%20When%20you,and%20columns.%20...%205%20Users%20and%20permissions.%20)) rather than pages in the SitePages library.

Comment: I think we already have that enabled... not in front of it right now to check. But in any case it would be a lift to change our architecture away from the SitePages library since we have menus and links that point to pages in there, and we have 20 sites. Is there anyway to just change the format of what SitePages gives you?

Comment: I'm just going to make the SitePages library read-only. If they need to make pages, I'll keep the Publishing Infrastructure feature in mind and then they can make pages in the "Pages" library, instead, like you said, assuming it's at the site level where we can control it.

Comment: Actually, I found the only way I could make the library read-only would be to change the access level on the groups people were in, and that was a non-starter as we can't tell the Owners group they are no longer owners, just for example. IDK what I was thinking. So what I found was that the SitePages folder acts just like another library in that you can go to "Advanced" within its settings and set the value to *Classic* there, just like you can do with other lists and libraries.